# uploading an image api in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms

I'm building an api to store an image as part of the machine model class to consuming it in the xamarin.forms so this is the machine class:

```cs
 public class Machine
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public string Machine_Qr { get; set; }
        public string Machine_Name { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the machine controller:

```cs
public class MachineController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public MachineController(DataContext context, IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            _context = context;
            _hostingEnvironment = environment ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(environment));



        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Machine>> Create(Machine machine)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
                foreach (var Image in files)
                {
                    if (Image != null && Image.Length > 0)
                    {

                        var file = Image;
                        var uploads = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads\\img\\Machines");

                        if (file.Length > 0)
                        {
                            var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse
                                (file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

                            System.Console.WriteLine(fileName);
                            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                            {
                                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                                machine.Image = file.FileName;
                            }


                        }
                    }
                }

                _context.Add(machine);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            }
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(PostMachine), new { id = machine.Machine_Qr }, machine);
        }
```

But when I'm trying to test the api in swagger I got this message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type: application/json
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Form()
   at WebApi.Controllers.MachineController.Create(Machine machine) in C:\Users\amyra\source\repos\WebApi\Controllers\MachineController.cs:line 35
```

The machineController line 35 is :

```cs
 var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should receive the Image as `IFormFile` property in your `Machine` class

```
[NotMapped]
public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
```

And then use `[FromForm]` attribute in your request

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Machine>> Create([FromForm] Machine machine)
```

Now you can remove these lines

```
var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
                foreach (var Image in files)
                {
                    
                }
```

And directly use `machine.Image` that you uploaded through Swagger

```
var file = machine.Image;
if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
{
    var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse
                                
    (file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

    System.Console.WriteLine(fileName);
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
        {
             await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
}
```

Comment: ok then how to store it as a column table in the database ?

Comment: @GazdallahAmira just remove `[NotMapped]` attribute

Comment: still the same error

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add something to my answer, I've updated it, and hope the problem is fixed now.

Comment: can you mention how to display the image in xamarin if you know?

Comment: sorry, I never used xamarin before. you can post another question so someone else could help